# When &self has different lifetime than the struct

Tags: rust, lifetime

On this example

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct A<'a, T> {
    elements: Vec<B<'a, T>>
}

pub struct B<'a, T> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>
}

impl<'a, T> A<'a, T> {
    pub fn iter(& self) -> Iter<'a, T> {
        Iter {
            iter: self.elements.iter(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct Iter<'a, T> {
    iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, B<'a, T>>,
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e246ef19b9ae5f1d405bde7c59d456d7

I get

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:14:24
   |
14 |             iter: self.elements.iter(),
   |                                 ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:17
//...
```

I know why this happens: the `elements` in `self.elements` lives as long as `&self`, so it cannot possibly create an `Iter` with lifetime `a`. The easy solution would be to do

```
pub fn iter(&'a self) -> Iter<'a, T> {
    Iter {
        iter: self.elements.iter(),
    }
}
```

but then I'm forced to borrow the `&self` for its entire existence which leads me to other problems. Whatis the easiest solution here?

Comment: *"but then I'm forced to borrow the `&self` for its entire existence"* - that's not quite true in the code presented code, `B` is covariant over `'a`, so the compiler can shorten the lifetime to only as long as its needed, not necessarily its whole lifetime.

Comment: @kmdreko nice! I think that on my harder example, it was invariant. Unfortunately I always forget some aspect before translating to a MVP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Iter` implementation is over-constrained; you have two unrelated lifetimes that are required to be the same. You should separate them:

```
impl<'a, T> A<'a, T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'a, '_, T> {
        Iter {
            iter: self.elements.iter(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct Iter<'a, 'b, T> {
    iter: std::slice::Iter<'b, B<'a, T>>,
}
```

That way, even if `'a` is invariant, you don't run into issues with linking that lifetime to `self`. See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9270e0b1107e23f9e9e599201e69cd47) (with additional tests).